# two instance of the same controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I run into this problem (I know it's not a good practice). I have a single view that has a split screen. On the left side you have an input field and on the right side you see the input field value. Both of the sides has the same controller, but I use the state provider with `ui-view` attribute.

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ui-view="left-side">
<div class="col-sm-6" ui-view="right-side">
```

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider.state('/',{
        url: '/',
         views:{
            'left-side':  {
                templateUrl: 'leftside.html',
                controller: 'testController'
            },
            'right-side': {
                 templateUrl: 'rightside.html'
                 controller: 'testController'
            }
        }
```

**rightside.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

**leftside.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <input ng-model="item" />
</div>
```

and in the **testController.js**

```
app.controller('testController, function($scope){
    $scope.item = 'some text value';
});
```

I know that each of the ui-view has a seperate (instance of?) scope.
Is there a way to make the changes on the right side if i write something in the input field on the left side?

Answer (score 4):

You can declare `controller` option outside views, so that will initialize only once

**Code**

```
$stateProvider.state('/',{
    url: '/',
    controller: 'testController',
    views:{
       'left-side':  {
       templateUrl: 'leftside.html'
    },
      'right-side': {
       templateUrl: 'rightside.html
    }
}
```